# Set ItemContainerStyle property within ItemTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have ItemsControl with Canvas as ItemsPanel.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Characters, ElementName=Playground}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="5" x:Name="PlaygroundCanvas" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <v:CharacterControl 
                    PlayerName="{Binding PlayerName}" 
                    CharacterImage="{Binding CharacterImage}"
                    FrameWidth="{Binding FrameWidth}" 
                    FrameHeight="{Binding FrameHeight}"
                    Location="{Binding Location}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Within my CharacterControl is possible to change Canvas.Left property  programmatically?

Actually I wanna bind animation to this style property I came up with this but it's not working at all CharacterControl.xaml.cs:

```
_movementAnimation = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("Movement");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(_movementAnimation, this);
```

Animation specified in CharacterControl.xaml like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Storyboard x:Key="Movement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.750" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: There should be a `public double X { get; set; }` property (with change notification) in the element class of your `Characters` collection, which you bind the `Canvas.Left` property to, like `<Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>`.

Comment: I see but I want to use animation.

Comment: I also tried to define animation in xaml but I had issue biding From and To because properties are freezable so I decided to use code behind but now I dont know how to access this property from ItemTemplate.